# Multi boxs css hover

Tags: html, css

I want to make a box pack includes 5 below.
When leaving the mouse on a box, the box extend to whole main div and display of rest of the boxes set to none.
in this code, just box1's mouse hover well extend.

These are my codes.

```css
.multibox{
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.multibox div{
  position: absolute;
  transition:  width 0.5s, height 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:  width 0.5s, height 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s; /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition:  width 0.5s, height 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition:  width 0.5s, height 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s; /* Opera */
  -ms-transition:  width 0.5s, height 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s; /* IE9 (maybe) */
}

.box1{
  background: gray;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  position: initial !important;
}
.box1:hover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box2{
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: initial !important;  
}
.box2:hover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box3{
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  position: initial !important;  
}
.box3:hover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box4{
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  position: initial !important;  
}
.box4:hover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box5
{
  background: brown;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: initial !important;
}
.box5:hover{
  width:300px;
  height: 300px;
  
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="multibox">
   <div class="box1">
      box 1
   </div>
   <div class="box2">
      box 2
   </div>
   <div class="box3">
      box 3
   </div>
   <div class="box4">
      box 4
   </div>
   <div class="box5">
      box 5
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

In which part have made a mistake?

Comment: "the box is great and the rest of the boxes disappear. But this is a mistake"  what effect are you trying to achieve? what is your code not doing that it should?

Comment: are you trying to have the other boxes disappear when you hover over one?

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it doesn't make sense now.

Comment: when you Run code snippet, just action of the box1 is my purpose. the  others run in wrong actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all boxes `position:absolute` and place them properly.

```css
.multibox{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
border: 1px solid black;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
.multibox div{
  position: absolute;
  transition:  all 0.5s, height 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:  all 0.5s, height 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s; /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition:  all 0.5s, height 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition:  all 0.5s, height 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s; /* Opera */
  -ms-transition:  all 0.5s, height 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0.5s; /* IE9 (maybe) */
}

.multibox div:hover{
z-index: 99;
}
.box1{
  background: gray;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 0;
top: 0;
  display: block;
}
.box1:hover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box2{
  background: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  display: block; 
}
.box2:hover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.box3{
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
top: 50px;
}
.box3:hover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
top: 0;
}

.box4{
  background: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  left: 50px;
top: 50px; 
}
.box4:hover{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}

.box5
{
  background: brown;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
.box5:hover{
  width:300px;
  height: 300px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="multibox">
  <div class="box1">
     box 1
  </div>
  <div class="box2">
     box 2
  </div>
  <div class="box3">
     box 3
  </div>
  <div class="box4">
     box 4
  </div>
  <div class="box5">
     box 5
  </div>
 </div>
```